# Смена настроек css для следующего блока через javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, которую я хочу вызывать через `validtext(name);` не прописывая `ClassName`, но в таком формате не работает строка для обработки следующего блока:

```
function validtext($text) {   
$text[0].next(".error_block").css("display","block");}
```

При вызове функции через `ClassName`, всё работает в таком формате, но меня это не устраивает.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".text_valid").after("<p class='error_block'>Поле не заполнено!!!</p>");
$(".text_valid").change(function(){
  var text_val = $(this)[0].value;     
  if (text_val == "" || text_val == " ") {
    $(this).removeClass("accept");
    $(this).addClass("error");
    $(this).next(".error_block").css("display","block");  
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("error");
    $(this).addClass("accept");
    $(this).next(".error_block").css("display","none");  
  }
});});

<input type="text" class="text_valid" placeholder="Имя"  name="name">
<p class='error_block'>Поле не заполнено!!!</p>
```

Что я делаю не так?

PS Javascript не знаю, изучаю на ходу по необходимости.

Как вариант не срабатывает потому что строка Поле не заполнено!!!

генерируется тоже при помощи JS, но в дереве обьектов браузера я её вижу с момента загрузки страницы

Comment: не понятно, что значит _не прописывая ClassName_ и почему это вас не устраивает?

Comment: $(".text_valid").change(function(){}; в данный момент чтоб вызвать функцию мне в HTML надо прописать класс блока, а нужно чтоб код не захламлялся и все функции вызывались в отдельном js файле

Comment: В планах обработка этими функциями всех блоков по нажатию на кнопку  submit,  и обработка в режиме онлайн по event .change

Comment: _обработка этими функциями всех блоков_ каких блоков? Как вы собираетесь определять какие блоки входят? прописать класс != захламить код

Comment: прописывается это для input блоков почтовой формы, чтоб при вводе имени или любого другого блока input менял цвет на зелёный при правильном заполении или красный при ошибке. А потом при отправке данных проходила проверка на ошибки и при их отсутствии передавала данные в пхп

Comment: function valid(form){
var name = document.getElementsByName("name");
validtext(name);} Вызов функции при отправке формы

Comment: Решение подсказали, у элемента нет метода next, нужен обьект jquery, у которого это метод есть, в таком формате заработало
$($text[0]).next

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, задача заключается в следующем:
Есть форма, в которой используются поля (допустим просто `input[type="text"]`), валидация заключается в том, чтобы проверить инпут на пустоту, в случае если он пустой, выдать под ним ошибку.

Если я правильно понял, то могу предложить вот такой вариант.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){

  InputValid(); // вызовим функцию

  return false;
});

// Сама функция
function InputValid() {
  $('form .valid').each(function(){// Перебераем все элементы с классом valid
    let val = $(this).val(), // Берём текущее значение value из элемента
        reg = /^[\s]*$/gi.test(val), // Регулярка, которая проверит, пустая ли строка
        error = $(this).next(); // берём следующий элемент (это для проверки, смотри ниже
    if(reg) {// Если пустая, то
      // Проверяем, если нету ниже элемента с классом error, то добавляем ошибку
      if(!error.hasClass('error')) $(this).after('<div class="error">Это поле не должно быть пустым!</div>'); // Создаём блок с ошибкой
    } else {// Если не пустая, то
      // если блок имеет класс error, то удалим его
      if(error.hasClass('error')) error.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input[type="text"] {
  width: 300px;
}

form .error {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

P.s.
Т.к. в метках стоит `jquery`, то код написан при помощи него.

---

**UPD** с разными проверками.

```js
$('form').submit(function(){

  InputValid();

  return false;
});

// Убрал старые подсказки, оставив только новые
function InputValid() {
  $('form .valid').each(function(){
    let val = $(this).val(),
        type = $(this).attr('type'),
        error = $(this).next(),
        regMath, errMess, regIf;
    
    switch(type){
      case "mail": // проверка на майл адрес
        regIf = true;
        regMath = /^[\w-\.]+@[\w-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
        errMess = 'Это не майл адрес';
        break;
      case "tel": // проверка на телефон
        regIf = true;
        regMath = /^\d[\d\(\)\ -]{4,14}\d$/;
        errMess = 'Это не номер телефона';
        break;
      default: // Стандартная проверка, на то, не является ли строка пустой
        regIf = false;
        regMath = /^[\s]*$/gi;
        errMess = 'Это поле не должно быть пустым';
    }
    
    let reg = regMath.test(val);
    if(reg != regIf) {
      if(!error.hasClass('error')) $(this).after('<div class="error">'+errMess+'</div>'); 
    } else {
      if(error.hasClass('error')) error.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form input:not([type="submit"]) {
  width: 300px;
}

form .error {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input class="valid" type="mail" placeholder="example@mail.ru">
  <input class="valid" type="tel" placeholder="8 123 456 78 90">
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input class="valid" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Это как пример забрасывал, есть и функции для обработки Емейл, телефона, длинны текста, допускающие ввод только букв, даты и .т.д. Для того что каждой строке не писать это всё, решил вызывать готовые ф-ции по ситуации

Comment: Почему не работало уже разобрался. У элемента нет метода next, нужен обьект jquery, у которого это метод есть              $($text[0]).next

Comment: Спасибо за вашу подсказку

Comment: @Михаил1, можно запихать внутрь проверки `switch()`, туда запихать проверку на `type`, допустим есть `type === "main"` (т.е. email), то выдаём проверку на емайл адрес, так для каждого.